Apache Beam Window Inconsistency Between DirectRunner and DataflowRunner
I have a test dataset to generate elements with timestamps in the next 20 minutes.  I want to create 1 minute fixed windows, and then create a 15 minute sliding window every minute from this.
n = 20
DURATION = 20 * 60
event_times = np.random.randint(1, DURATION + 1, n)
events = []
offset = 1_000_000_000
for i in range(n):
    events.append(offset + int(event_times[i]))

I am seeing OUTPUT_AT_EOW on the 15 minute sliding window has different behavior on DataflowRunner vs DirectRunner.
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    output = (
         p
         | "Create Timestamps" >> beam.Create([beam.window.TimestampedValue(f"Value {i}", i) for i in events])
         | "AssignWindow" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(60),
                                                 timestamp_combiner=beam.window.TimestampCombiner.OUTPUT_AT_EARLIEST)
         | "Assign15MinuteSlidingWindow" >> beam.WindowInto(
                beam.window.SlidingWindows(15 * 60, 60),
                timestamp_combiner=beam.window.TimestampCombiner.OUTPUT_AT_EOW,
                trigger=beam.trigger.AfterWatermark(),
                accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
                allowed_lateness=0,
            )
        | "Add Dummy Key" >> beam.Map(lambda x: ('key', x))
        | "Count Elements" >> beam.CombinePerKey(beam.combiners.CountCombineFn())
        | "Print Elements with Timestamps" >> beam.ParDo(PrintWithTimestampsAndWindow())
        | 'Write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)
    )

The discrepancy seen between the two runners (using EOW) looks like below (truncated result to keep short)
DirectRunner has properly aggregated, unique windows (from PrintWithTimestampsAndWindow())
('key', 13) @ 2001-09-09T01:55:59.999000Z in window [2001-09-09T01:41:00Z, 2001-09-09T01:56:00Z)

DataflowRunner has only windows with a few elements (<5), and lots of repeat windows, so roughly 3-4x more output than DirectRunner.
('key', 1) @ 2001-09-09T02:03:59.999000Z in window [2001-09-09T01:49:00Z, 2001-09-09T02:04:00Z)

Note, using OUTPUT_AT_EARLIEST instead here produces expected behavior between both runners.  What is going on here?  Why is EOW inconsistent here?
I have also tried using multi processing with several workers on DirectRunner to mimic Dataflow, to no success.  I am guessing this is due to something with watermarking across multiple workers and minute delays when using DataflowRunner, but hoping somebody could help me in understanding the cause on a deeper level.

If you only limit the number of Dataflow workers to 1, will you see any difference?

There seems to be no difference when setting dataflow worker to 1.
